# Getting "Missing SDK in target picChoice: iphoneos4.0" error when building a test release of my app in Xcode 4, pvw 5

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I have opened a functioning Xcode 3x project in Xcode 4.0 pvw 5 and am getting the following error whei I try to build a debug version of the app: "Missing SDK in target picChoice: iphoneos4.0"

I am trying to find where and how to remedy this, and I am coming up with bupkus.

I apologize if this is not very clear, but I am rather flummoxed by Xcode 4 so far....

Answer (score 8):

Your problem was probably that Xcode 4 only came with SDK 4.2, and the project pointed to 4.0.

It's pretty common!

The solution is to go to the project info | Build settings | Base SDK and setting it to "Latest iOS" so that you don't have to touch it for future updates.

When you close the window, you'll have to switch config from debug to release or distribution and back so that it updates and Xcode removes the "Missing SDK" problem.

I just wanted to put the full answer up here to help others who have the same problem ;)

Comment: Additional tip: set the 'Deployment Target' back down to 4.0 (or such as you desire) to ensure that your binary will launch on devices that haven't been upgraded. But it'll still be built against the 4.2 SDK so it's up to you to ensure you don't accidentally use anything that wasn't in 4.0, and definitely worth keeping a non-upgraded device around to test on.

Comment: Good answer! Should also not that we need to be looking at ALL rather than BASIC in the Build Settings tab.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...I resolved this, but I did not properly track HOW I resolved it....

I think my Target's Base SDK was not set, and I set it to: Latest iOS (iOS 4.2)....

I *think* that's how I did it....

But, now it builds with no errors and loads onto my iPhone as expected.

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what you needed to do.  Xcode 4 introduced the Latest iOS.  If you wish to test the app for older versions, select target > summary > deployment target and set that to an older iOS version and then in simulator you will see more version options available to you.